# What's the recommended way to enable versioning on a Dexterity custom content type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm developing a site with Plone 4.1 and Dexterity 1.0.1. I want to add versioning support to a Dexterity-based custom content type I'm developing. My content type is defined as a Python-based schema on the filesystem and not created throuugh the Dexterity web UI.

I found an article [here](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/how-to/adding-versioning-to-dexterity-content-types) however the link to the [article on enabling versioning for custom content types](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/appendix-practicals/enabling-versioning-on-your-custom-content-types) is based on Archetypes (I think?) so I'm not sure how I need to adapt this Dexterity and the link through to how to plug the code into GenericSetup is broken.

What's the recommended way of doing versioning with Dexterity content types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.versioningbehavior

Comment: Great, thanks. That worked. Looks like I was just missing the additional element from the list of behaviors for my content type.

Comment: I think it's also important that you upgrade your Dexterity version to 1.1; there are some issues in the previous release that are fixed in this one.